# Calling model with related data in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC web application I have created a model class called `TempInvoice` and another called `TempInvoiceItems`.

This `TempInvoiceItems` holds the foreign key of `TempInvoice` `ID`.

I want to know, when I use this in the controller:

```
TempInvoice tempInvoice = db.TempInvoice.Find(id);
```

should it get the data in `TempInvoice` and the `TempInvoiceItems` to the model ?

Here the list is returned as null.

I created virtual list in the `TempInvoice` and another virtual `ICollection` list but got nothing.

Can you help me with this issue? I'm new to this architecture and keen to know about this.

These are my models:

```
public class TempInvoice 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ? CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Payment_Type { get; set; }

    [Required]  
    public string Invoice_Number { get; set; }
    public decimal Discounted_Amount { get; set; } = decimal.Zero;
    public decimal Discounted_Precentage { get; set; }
    public decimal Invoice_Total_Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Invoice_Sub_Amount { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByEmpId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ? UpdatedByEmpId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
 
    [NotMapped]
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string CompanyPhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public decimal CollectedCustomerAmount { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<TempInvoiceItems> TempInvoiceItems { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<TempInvoiceItems>  { get; set; }
}

public class TempInvoiceItems 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TempInvoice")]
    public int Invoice_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual TempInvoice TempInvoice { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Items")]
    public int Item_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual EvoPOS.Models.Items.Items Items { get; set; }
 
    [Required]
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Unit_Price { get; set; }

    public decimal Line_Discount { get; set; } = decimal.Zero;
    public decimal Line_Total { get; set; }
    public string Extra_Note { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; } = true;

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByEmpId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedByEmpId { get; set; }

    public int Location_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use layz loading in your controller db.TempInvoice.Include(x => x.TempInvoiceItems).ToList();

Comment: @erdiyılmaz Hi, Thanks. So in your code how to get this thing done ``Find(id)`` ??

Comment: Find(id) use for child to parent(or one to one relation) but you want to use parent to children

Comment: @erdiyılmaz I didn't get you. I mean here in the view, I passed the ``TempInvoice`` Id to the controller, and there I want to get the data for the ``Id`` from the ``TempInvoice`` and the ``TempInvoiceItems``.

Comment: You need to Include for TempInvoiceItems list

Comment: Beginner your welcome